# Magento 1.9 EAV constraints, bug or mysql bug?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am trying to remove a `catalog_product` custom attribute the Magento way by using `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::removeAttribute()` but it results in bad data integrity: the attribute gets deleted from `eav_attribute` table but not from `catalog_eav_attribute`.

When doing

```
show create table catalog_eav_attribute
```

I see the the `attribute_id` *FK* to `eav_attribute` defined correctly with `on delete cascade` in place

Is this a known bug of Magento or rather a mysql bug?

Magento version is 1.9.2.2, mysql version is 5.5.46 running on ubuntu 14.04.2

Edit: I tried to reproduce the error by mocking a custom relationship between two custom tables using a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade enabled and it worked: when I deleted a row in the parent table, all related rows in child table were deleted accordingly. Why won't the same work for the `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` tables?

Edit2: the same happens with other tables referencing the `eav_attribute` table: `eav_attribute_option`, `eav_attribute_option_value`, `customer_eav_attribute`, etc, leaving Magento with lots of orphaned child rows in aforementioned tables.

Comment: You do understand that Magento is built on the EAV system? If you remove part of it or all of it Magento won't work.

Comment: The attribute in question is a custom attribute I have added previously. What do you mean by "Magento won't work"? :)

Comment: my bad, I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted to delete attributes from the EAV model. Have you tried deleting your attribute from the attribute panel in the backend? If so, what does it do?

Comment: There is magerun extension called Eav cleaner that can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are removing an attribute using an upgrade script and you have this line at the start of the file

```
$installer->startSetup();
```

remove it.
It just disables the foreign key checks.